# Deep clone/copy breeze entity and create new entity

Tags: arrays, entity-framework, clone, breeze

I'm trying to clone/copy my product entity with all of it's children but can get this to work. I use the export/import method but the children are not included and the id stays the same.

```
function cloneProduct(product) {

    console.log("product before export", product);

    var exportData = this.manager.exportEntities([product]);
    var manager2 = this.manager.createEmptyCopy();
    var importData = manager2.importEntities(exportData);

    console.log("product after import", importData);

    return importData;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

***UPDATE:***

For now I'm using the method provided on this question: [Breeze create entity from existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566093/breeze-create-entity-from-existing-one/20579971#20579971)

I don't know that is the correct way to use, but it gets the job done for now.

Answer (score 1):

We have nothing better to offer at this time than the answer to the SO question that you found: [Breeze create entity from existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566093/breeze-create-entity-from-existing-one/20579971#20579971).

A configured-deep clone is on our backlog. Would you mind [voting for it here](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5892328-deep-entity-clone-with-configuration-for-dependent)?