# Breeze - Édit row in modal strategy

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, breeze

I've been using breeze with angularJS in my last few projects, but there's something I never had done right, at least with a good strategy. That's editing/adding rows in one modal.

In the previous projets, my strategy was to clone the breeze objects into json objects and then editing that objects in the modal. This strategy wasn't quite good, because I lost the power to breeze to validate the objet's.

So in this new projet, I change that strategy, and I [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566093/breeze-create-entity-from-existing-one) the breeze object into another breeze object and at the end of editing, I merge the changes into the original object. 
The problem with this last stategy is, if I create a new breeze object(attached), the objects are added to entity manager and at the end I have to remove him and is navigation objects. If I create a new breeze object ( dettached) I loose the automatic validations and the navigation properties. So I gain nothing in this last strategy.

Note : I always clone the object in all strategies, because I'm using angularJS and I don't want the user to see the object being modified in the list at same time he's editing the object in the modal.

[image: Editing some row in a modal]

So, my question is what is the best way to accomplish this, using breeze and angularJS? 
I didn't find any breezeJS recommendations on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [multiple entity managers](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/multiple-managers) for this.  Rather than clone an object in the same manager, you should create a separate EntityManager for the modal dialog.  Then all changes in the dialog will happen in that EntityManager, and if the user choose to discard the changes, you can discard that EntityManager and the rest of your data will be intact.

See the [Multiple EntityManagers](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/multiple-managers) documentation for how to do this, and see the [TempHire](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/temphire-sample) sample application for an example.  TempHire uses Knockout instead of Angular, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use multiple entity managers, in some scenarios, but never thought of use them in this particular scenario.
That's a very good approach and was exactly what I want.